# Printing labels on Brother QL-800 printer from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a "Run-Time error 91:  Object variable or With block variable not set" error when running this code to print from an Excel VBA application:

```
Public Sub PrintLabel(thisName, thisCashPrice, thisCardPrice, thisUPC, thisItemID, thisPrintQty)
Dim labelInfo As String, sPath As String, ObjDoc As bpac.Document
          
    'Create a b-PAC object
    Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")

    'Open a template file created with P-touch Editor
    '(Put this Excel file and the template file in then same folder)
    sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "RRRCamp.lbx"
    ObjDoc.Open (sPath)
    
    '   Test to determine if ObjDoc is open
    test = ObjDoc.SetPrinter("Brother QL-800", True)

    ' Open lbx file

    If ObjDoc.Open(sPath) Then
        Debug.Print "Opened lbx file"
    End If

    ObjDoc.GetObject("objProductName").text = thisName
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objCashPrice").text = thisCashPrice
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objCardPrice").text = thisCardPrice

    ObjDoc.GetObject("objUPC").text = thisUPC
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objItemID").text = thisItemID
    
    
    'Print
    ObjDoc.StartPrint "DocumentName", bpoAutoCut
    ObjDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoAutoCut
    ObjDoc.EndPrint

    
    'Free the b-PAC object
    ObjDoc.Close
    Set ObjDoc = Nothing


End Sub
```

I have created a template file using P-Touch Editor that looks like this:

[P-touch editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI3wB.jpg)

Running on Office 365, Windows 11. Updated printer firmware.

ObjDoc is opening and lbx template file is opening as expected. When trying to set values for data fields

```
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objProductName").text = thisName
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objCashPrice").text = thisCashPrice
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objCardPrice").text = thisCardPrice

    ObjDoc.GetObject("objUPC").text = thisUPC
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objItemID").text = thisItemID
```

I'm passing the values to be set as arguments in the PrintLabel sub - they all seem to be correct values.

I get the "Object variable or With block variable not set" error.

Tried changing Target to "User Information" in P-touch Editor but no success.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: You need to debug it and check if `ObjDoc.GetObject("objProductName")` resolves to an object. Try This. `Dim obj as Object` and then in the next line `Set obj = ObjDoc.GetObject("objProductName")`. Put a breakpoint on this line and check obj resolves to a valid object. You can also use a watch to check the value, type etc

Comment: ObjDoc.GetObject("objProductName").text = thisName generates the error.

ObjDoc.GetObject("objProductName") does NOT resolve to a valid object - it shows "Nothing".  Is there something I've missed in the P-touch Editor that's causing this?

Comment: A backslash is needed in the path `sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "RRRCamp.lbx"`

Comment: Thanks Black cat - added. Still doesn't impact ObjDoc.GetObject error.

Answer (score 2):

Got this working. The problem was the way Excel handles paths with OneDrive - the statement "ActiveWorkbook.path" returns a string that is a path to the OneDrive file location. This could be solved by hard-coding the local path to the .lbx file location. It can also be solved by calculating the local path using this code:

```
    Public Function GetLocalPath(ByVal Path As String) As String

Const HKCU = &H80000001
Dim objReg As Object, rPath As String, subKeys(), subKey
Dim urlNamespace As String, mountPoint As String, secPart As String

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\." & _
                       "\root\default:StdRegProv")
                       
rPath = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"
objReg.EnumKey HKCU, rPath, subKeys

For Each subKey In subKeys
    objReg.GetStringValue HKCU, rPath & subKey, "UrlNamespace", urlNamespace
    If InStr(Path, urlNamespace) > 0 Then
        objReg.GetStringValue HKCU, rPath & subKey, "MountPoint", mountPoint
        secPart = Replace(Mid(Path, Len(urlNamespace)), "/", "\")
        Path = mountPoint & secPart
        Do Until Dir(Path, vbDirectory) <> "" Or InStr(2, secPart, "\") = 0
            secPart = Mid(secPart, InStr(2, secPart, "\"))
            Path = mountPoint & secPart
        Loop
        Exit For
    End If
Next

GetLocalPath = Path
    
End Function
```

Either of these remedies provides the local path needed to correctly identify the P-Touch editor template file's (.lbx) location

Here's the final working code:

```
    Public Sub PrintLabel(thisName, thisCashPrice, thisCardPrice, thisUPC, thisItemID, thisPrintQty)
    Dim labelInfo As String, sPath As String, localPath As String, ObjDoc As bpac.Document
          
    'Create a b-PAC object
    Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")

    'Open a template file created with P-touch Editor
    '(Put this Excel file and the template file in then same folder)
    sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "RRRCamp.lbx"
    localPath = GetLocalPath(sPath)

    ObjDoc.Open (localPath)
    
    ' Assign values to the object fields
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objProductName").text = thisName
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objCashPrice").text = thisCashPrice
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objCardPrice").text = thisCardPrice

    ObjDoc.GetObject("objUPC").text = thisUPC
    
    ObjDoc.GetObject("objItemID").text = thisItemID
    
    
    'Print
    ObjDoc.StartPrint "DocumentName", bpoAutoCut
    ObjDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoAutoCut
    ObjDoc.EndPrint

    
    'Free the b-PAC object
    ObjDoc.Close
    Set ObjDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```